Prisma askes for db reset on migration after adding postgresqlExtensions
I use prisma ORM for my project.
When I add a single line previewFeatures = ["postgresqlExtensions"] and run prisma migrate dev, Prisma detects a drift and asks me to reset the database.
There shouldn't be any conflicts with the existing data since I just added the extensions but never applied them to my existing models.
Also, there is no drift if I remove that single line. i.e. the current schema has no conflicts with the existing migration history either.
Any idea what is causing the drift? Is there a way to do prisma migrate dev without wiping the entire database or should I just resolve to prisma db push instead?
Any advises will be truly appreciated.
